# corrupting golang file when saving in visual studio code

Tags: go, visual-studio-code, save, corruption

When I save a golang file in visual studio code, it ends up being corrupted -- characters are removed, not in any pattern I have discerned. This has occurred at various times in the past, but has just now recurred. For details, see my bug report, "corrupting file when saving in visual studio code #49465"[1](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/49465).

In the meantime, what I can do until it's fixed? Perhaps I could return to an older version of gopls, but I don't know how to do that.

Any suggestions welcome. I'm stuck until I can successfully save and run my go programs.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try running the following command

```
GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@master golang.org/x/tools@master
```

or

```
GO111MODULE=on go get golang.org/x/tools/gopls@v0.3.2-pre1
```

Comment: Thanks, but didn't work. I tried the first one (...tools@master) but it did not change the behavior. I then tried the second one (...gopls@v0.3.2-pre1). Its installation failed. It started out with the (by now expected)

> go get: installing executables with 'go get' in module mode is
> deprecated.

and then reported a series of errors, ending with

> C:\Users\xxxxx\go\pkg\mod\golang.org\x\tools\gopls@v0.3.2-pre1\internal\hooks\hooks.go:17:24:
> too many errors

Answer (score 0):

In order to make progress on my project, I've downloaded the [prior version of `go`](https://golang.org/dl/). At least on Windows, the downgrade installs like any upgrade, including offering to remove the existing version.

And I backed up `gopls` to its previous version using the facilities of VS Code:

- <kbd>ctrl+shift+X</kbd> to access extensions
- right-click on *Go*
- select *Install Another Version*
- wait...wait...wait...
- when the list of versions finally appears, select the one you want (I went back a month)

So, the underlying problem still exists, but I'm back in business. I hope these instructions can help someone else battling with the disappearing character bug.